# Webcam api : Maximizing the 720p capture

Tags: java, webcam-capture

I am attempting to capture a video recording through an external camera, Logitec C922. Using java, I can make this possible through webcam api.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
        <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
        <version>5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, for the life of me, I cannot make it record at 60FPS. The video randomly stutters when stored, and is not smooth at all.

I can connect to the camera, using the following details.

```
final List<Webcam> webcams = Webcam.getWebcams();

for (final Webcam cam : webcams) {
    if (cam.getName().contains("C922")) {
        System.out.println("### Logitec C922 cam found");
        webcam = cam;
        break;
    }
}
```

I set the size of the cam to the following:

```
final Dimension[] nonStandardResolutions = new Dimension[] { WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize(), };
webcam.setCustomViewSizes(nonStandardResolutions);
webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize());
webcam.open(true);
```

And then I capture the images:

```
while (continueRecording) {
    // capture the webcam image
    final BufferedImage webcamImage = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    final Date timeOfCapture = new Date();

    // convert the image and store
    final IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(webcamImage, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
    final IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(webcamImage,
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);

    frame.setKeyFrame(false);
    frame.setQuality(0);
    writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);

}
```

My writer is defined as follows:

```
final Dimension size = WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize();
final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(videoFile.getName());
writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);
```

I am honestly not sure what in my code could be causing this. Given that I lower the resolution, I get no problems. ( 480p ) Could the issue be with the codes I am using?

Comment: WHICH webcam API are you using?

Comment: I found the `API` [here](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/).

Comment: I was looking at the example code and comparing it to yours, and I noticed your `Thread`/loop does not have `Thread.sleep(100);` >[example code](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-video-recording/src/main/java/com/github/sarxos/webcam/Encoder.java). I think that's how he keeps up with how many frames per seconds. Are you familiar with `JavaFX`? I have written a sample app in `JavaFX`.

Comment: @JimGarrison Api documentation that Sedric provided is correct. I've updated the question with the maven coordinates

Comment: @Sedrick I've added a sleep thread for 33, or even 100 ms, but if anything, it degrades the performance.  Leaving it out helps

Comment: @Sedrick also, Sleeping will most likely destroy the FPS count. 60, or high 50's are really important for me to keep

Comment: My camera can capture up to 640x480. So I can't test your problem. Sorry.

Comment: I  think your problem has to do with the time it takes to create the HD frame.   I am currently reading a book about developing games in Java->[Killer Game Programming](http://www.reedbushey.com/106Killer%20Game%20Programming%20in%20Java.pdf0). The book talked about a topic that reminded me of your problem.  Basically, what I think is happening is that the time needed to create an HD frame is causing some frames to be missed.

Comment: Are you just grabbing the latest frame as fast as the PC allows? I don't know if that API call (`webcam.getImage()`) is blocking, but otherwise it sounds like what you need is a listener to be notified of new frames.

Comment: Also if CPU is the bottleneck try delegating resize/encode operations to a threadpool.

Comment: This is a python example https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/, but you will notice how the FPS jumps from 35 to 140+ by introducing threading. And you have to use the same in your case. One thread to capture raw data in image and put it in Queue and the other threads to process and write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the comments mentioned, introducing queues does solve the problem. Here is the general logic to performs the needed steps. Note, I've setup my code for a lower resolution, as it allows me to capture 100FPS per sec. Adjust as needed.

Class to link the image/video capture and class to edit it :

```
public class WebcamRecorder {

    final Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();
    final Stopper stopper = new Stopper();

    public void startRecording() throws Exception {

        final Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setViewSize(size);
        webcam.open(true);

        final BlockingQueue<CapturedFrame> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<CapturedFrame>();
        final Thread recordingThread = new Thread(new RecordingThread(queue, webcam, stopper));
        final Thread imageProcessingThread = new Thread(new ImageProcessingThread(queue, size));

        recordingThread.start();
        imageProcessingThread.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        stopper.setStop(true);
    }

}
```

RecordingThread :

```
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("## capturing images began");
        while (true) {
            final BufferedImage webcamImage = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            final Date timeOfCapture = new Date();
            queue.put(new CapturedFrame(webcamImage, timeOfCapture, false));
            if (stopper.isStop()) {
                System.out.println("### signal to stop capturing images received");
                queue.put(new CapturedFrame(null, null, true));
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("### threading issues during recording:: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.out.println("## capturing images end");
        if (webcam.isOpen()) {
            webcam.close();
        }
    }
}
```

ImageProcessingThread:

```
public void run() {
    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);
    try {
        int frameIdx = 0;
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            final CapturedFrame capturedFrame = queue.take();
            if (capturedFrame.isEnd()) {
                break;
            }
            final BufferedImage webcamImage = capturedFrame.getImage();
            size.height);

            // convert the image and store
            final IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(webcamImage, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
            final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(webcamImage, (end - start) * 1000);

            frame.setKeyFrame((frameIdx++ == 0));
            frame.setQuality(0);
            writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);
        }
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("### threading issues during image processing:: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

The way it works is pretty simple. The WebcamRecord class creates an instance of a queue that is shared between the video capture and the image processing. The RecordingThread sends bufferedImages to the queue ( in my case, it a pojo, called CapturedFrame ( which has a BufferedImage in it ) ). The ImageProcessingThread will listen and pull data from the queue. If it does not receive a signal that the writing should end, the loop never dies.